How are the equilibrium constants for constant pressure and constant volume related?
The equilibrium constant $K$ determines the ratio between products and reactants in a chemical reaction to maximize the total entropy. For systems with a specified pressure $p$, we can minimize the Gibbs free energy to find $K_p$, and for specified volume $V$, we can minimize the Helmholtz free energy to find $K_V$. This is spelled out in this answer: Can we have an equilibrium constant for a reaction at constant volume?
I am considering closed containers so that I would use the $K_V$ values for my chemical reactions. However, my literature seems to provide the corresponding $K_p$ values instead.
My question is, how are $K_V$ and $K_p$ related?
I expect the answer to be along the following lines.
They are related through a Legendre transformation.
Perhaps the issue is similar to how the heat capacities at constant volume and pressure are related.
Perhaps they are just equal in all (some) cases.
Or they could be unrelated, which I doubt is the correct answer.

K_p does not mean at constants pressure, but expressed in (partial) pressures K_V could be expressed in partial molar volumes, resp. their reciprocal values.  The true thermodynamic constants are expressed via activities or fugacities., dependent only on temperature Non TD constant K_p or K_c are not exactly constant, but, aside of T, depend also on pressure and composition.

They are relted by a simple equation:
Kp = Kc(RT)Δn *Only works for reversible reactions

Thank you, but I am unable to follow your reasoning. A more elaborate answer instead of a comment would be helpful.

As @poutnik notes, there's no such thing as an equilibrium constant for
a constant volume process, though $K_{c}$ is convenient for calculations at
constant volume.
I'll assume ideal gases throughout. Let $K^{\ominus }$ be the equilibrium
constant relative to the 1 bar pressure standard state, and $p^{\ominus }=1$
bar. Since this is the standard state for gases in thermodynamic tables,
this is the value you get from looking up Gibbs energies of formation and
calculating using
$$
\Delta _{\mathrm{r}}G^{\ominus }=-RT\ln K^{\ominus }
$$
For example, for
$$
\ce{2NO2 <=> N2O4}
$$
at $25{}^\circ\mathrm{C}$, $K^{\ominus }=6.74$ and at equilibrium this equals the reaction
quotient $Q^{\ominus }$:
$$
K^{\ominus }=\frac{\left( p_{N2O4}/p^{\ominus }\right) }{\left(
p_{NO2}/p^{\ominus }\right) ^{2}}
$$
(If one ignores the $p^{\ominus }$ and remembers to express the partial
pressure in units of bars, then this becomes $K_{p}$.)
Let $K^\circ$ be the equilibrium constant relative to the $\pu{1 mol dm^{-3}}$ ($\pu{1 M}$) standard
state, and $c^\circ=\pu{1 mol dm^{-3}}$. For the example reaction we have
$K^\circ =167.08$ and at equilibrium
$$
K^\circ 
=\frac{\left( c_{\ce{N2O4}}/c^\circ \right) }{\left( c_{\ce{NO2}}/c^\circ \right) ^{2}}
$$
(If one ignores the $c^\circ$ and remembers to express the concentration in units of $\pu{mol dm^{-3}}$, then
this becomes $K_{c}$.) The relationship between these is
$$
K^\circ =K^{\ominus }\left( \frac{p^{\ominus }}{RTc^\circ} \right) ^{\Delta _{\mathrm{r}}\nu }
$$
where $\Delta _{\mathrm{r}}\nu $ is the number of molecules of products
minus the number of molecules of reactants; $-1$ in the example. This
relationship is often written without $p^{\ominus }$ or $c^\circ$, but since the numerical value of $p^{\ominus }/{c^\circ} = \pu{100 J/mol}$, this can lead to difficulties unless one is very careful about
the units. To derive this relationship, one takes the $K^{\ominus}=Q^{\ominus }$ and rearranges to find the value of $Q^\circ$.
Some explanations. Whether we minimize the Helmholtz energy at constant
volume and temperature, or the Gibbs energy at constant pressure and
temperature, the equilibrium condition is that the same: chemical potential
of products minus chemical potential of reactants is zero, which we write as
$\Delta _{\mathrm{r}}G=0$. Once we are at equilibrium at a particular pressure, volume, and
temperature, this condition is satisfied whether we approached this by a
constant volume or constant pressure process.
Consider the example reaction run at constant volume, starting with $\pu{1 mol}$
each of $\ce{NO2}$ and $\ce{N2O4}$ in a $\pu{25 mol dm^{-3}}$ container. The initial concentrations
are $\pu{0.04 mol dm^{-3}}$ and the equilibrium concentrations are $\pu{0.04 mol} -2x$ for $\ce{NO2}$
and $\pu{0.04 mol} +x$ for $\ce{N2O4}$. Using these in the expression above for $K^\circ$, we solve for $x$ and find the equilibrium concentrations to be
$c_{\ce{NO2}} = \pu{0.0175 mol dm^{-3}}$ and $c_{\ce{N2O4}} = \pu{0.0512 mol dm^{-3}}$.
Because the total pressure is changing, this cannot be done quite as simply
with pressures and $K^{\ominus }$. However, if we consider that the change
in moles of $\ce{N2O4}$ is the extent of reaction $\xi $, then at equilibrium the
moles of $\ce{NO2}$ and $\ce{N2O4}$ are $\pu{1 mol}-2\xi $ and $\pu{1 mol}+\xi $. After converting these to
partial pressures with $p=nRT/V$, they may be inserted into the expression
for $K^{\ominus }$ above and solved for $\xi $. The same equilibrium
concentrations (or pressures) are found as in the first method.
So the amount of work to convert from $K^{\ominus }$ to $K^\circ$ may not be justified.

I guess that might mean K_p = K_V in the link in the question, but since that quantity wasn't clearly defined, that is hard to say. I agree there may be differences in the case of reactions not involving ideal gases, but that is a more subtle point.

Thank you. I find the part stating that minimizing Gibbs and Helmholtz free energy being equivalent particularly relevant. Can you recommend a reference for me to understand this better? You seem to assume that the chemical potentials are identical in the two cases. That is not clear to me.

I don't have a reference. I derived this to my satisfaction using some statistical mechanics (Sackur-Tetrode) for ideal gases to shortcut the derivation. For me that gives more physical insight, but a purist might object it's not a purely thermodynamic derivation. If that is acceptable to you I can add it to my answer.

Actually, I didn't claim that minimizing Gibbs and Helmholtz free energies are equivalent, just that the relationships between the chemical potentials at the minima are the same.
